# VS Code debug not stopping on breakpoints

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, debugging, vscode-debugger

I'm new to using VS Code as I've always used Eclipse IDE.
I'm trying to debug my java file in which I've created a breakpoint, but the debugger just runs the code as if there wasn't such a breakpoint.

I've seen some other people struggle with this, so here's my launch.json:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Java",
            "type": "java",
            "request": "launch",
            "stopOnEntry": true,
            "jdkPath": "${env:JAVA_HOME}/bin",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "startupClass": "${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "classpath": [
                ".",
                "${fileDirname}"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Java Console App",
            "type": "java",
            "request": "launch",
            "stopOnEntry": true,
            "jdkPath": "${env:JAVA_HOME}/bin",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "startupClass": "${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "classpath": [
                ".",
                "${fileDirname}"
            ],
            "externalConsole": true
        },
        {
            "type": "java",
            "name": "Current File",
            "request": "launch",
            "mainClass": "${file}"
        },
        {
            "type": "java",
            "name": "Numeros",
            "request": "launch",
            "mainClass": "Numeros",
            "projectName": "progra_4bad0bd0"
        }
    ]
}
```

I've tried using other jdk (right now I'm using Oracle) but it doesn't work

Comment: Have you installed the [Debugger for Java](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-java-debug) extension?

Answer (score 0):

You need to start debugging from the **Run and Debug** panel using the green button, so that the configuration in *launch.json* will be used. You can select the debug configuration in *launch.json* in the drop-down menu.

[image]

You can also use `Run --> Start Debugging` to start debugging.

[image]